# SQL DB using data from one table to another

Tags: mysql

Good evening!
I have a database with two tables (users and customers)

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    id int(11) NOT NULL,
    fullname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    phone varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    trip varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    timePeriod varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    departureDate date NOT NULL,
    payment decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
    display varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    country varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    persons int(11) NOT NULL,
    comments text DEFAULT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE users (
    id int(11) NOT NULL,
    fullname varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    role enum('admin','user') NOT NULL
)
```

I want to add a column to the customers table named manager.
There I want to display a list with all the names from the users table.

I add a column to the customers table

```
manager int(11) DEFAULT NULL
```

but when I try to add a new customer, it displays the users' id and not the full names (see photo).

Anyone any solution!!!
Thanks in advance!

[image]